# The schema version of 'Newtonsoft.Json' is incompatible

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nugetgallery

I am using Visual Studio Express Web 2012. Recently, my computer crashed so have switched to a new laptop. The same visual studio after restoring the code is throwing an error as:

> The schema version of 'Newtonsoft.Json' is incompatible with version
>   2.2.40116.9051 of NuGet.

Of course, VS suggests:

> Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.

I did upgrade NuGet but still I'm receiving the same problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried updating to VS 2015? It looks like the latest NuGet versions are compatible with either VS 2013 or 2015.

Here is 2015 Community edition that you can download free:
https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Comment: Yes, I tried it and worked but then also noticed in Visual Studio VS 2012 (Express) which it my working platform there is an update under `Tools > Extension and Updates > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery` so after updating it, VS required me to restart it and then everything came back up.  Thank you, Jonathan!